# Mage the Awakening: magic map creation arcana involved

Tags: spells, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

Let's say a player wants to create a map to locate nearby vampires and give it to his mates in order to better protect themselves.

I think that Space, Death and Matter are involved:

- Space to locate creatures
- Death to locate specifically Vampires
- Matter to modify/create markers on the map

At this point, I am stuck. Do you think Prime 3 is mandatory to imbue the spell into the physical object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I'd say Space, Death, and Prime.

You're on target with the use of Death and Space, and the need for Prime to turn the spell into an Imbued item, but there's no need for Matter here -- once you use the Arcanum of Death to allow the user to perceive the vampires, changing the physical matter of the map is superfluous. The information will be imparted, and you can describe it as "moving dots on the map."